QVideoSink in Qt6.7
I was just wondering if it was possible to play a video using QVideoSink in Qt without using the concepts of multimedia in qml i.e Video and VideoOutput because my target device is not supporting multimedia concepts in qml. I checked the below question
How to use QVideoSink in QML in Qt6
But they have also used multimedia in qml

QVideoSink belong QtMultimedia

I recommend the Gstreamer. The mechanism under the QtMultimedia is Gstreamer
